# Where can I download the Gnome 3 Icons?

Tags: icons, gnome

After poking around on the Internet for awhile, I haven't been able to find the default icons used in Gnome 3 anywhere.  My requirements are fairly simple:

- SVGs would be nice, but not necessary
- This **doesn't** need to be installable as an icon theme in Ubuntu
- A compressed folder with all of the icons would be good, but I don't mind browsing a repository and downloading individual icons.

As a last resort, I could always download a full Gnome 3 iso and find the icons that way, but hopefully someone knows of a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to get the icons from the [gnome-icon-theme git repository](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-icon-theme/log/?h=master).

Adapted [installation instructions from WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/download-latest-gnome-icon-theme-via.html):

- Install git (if you don't have it
  already).
- Then run `git clone git://git.gnome.org/gnome-icon-theme`
- You have to compile the icon theme using the standard `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr`, `./configure`, `make`, `make install` or `sudo make install`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!  I haven't tried compiling/installing it yet, but I have the actual files, which was the real goal.